# Get the content of iframe which generated on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an iframe which is generated on the fly and appended in a div like this:

```
content.innerHTML = '<iframe src="' + url + '" id="id_iframe" style="border:0px #BD8D46 dotted;" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" align="center"></iframe>';
```

The div which is appended in invisible (display: none;)

What I want to do is to change the display of the div according to the content of the iframe.

I try this

```
console.log($("#id_iframe").contents());
```

But I get nothing back. No contents. When I use the developers tools I see that the iframe exists in the DOM.

Is it possible to get the iframe content on the fly?

Comment: Is it from same domain as the main page? If not, you can't access it. If it is then use a load event

Comment: I think this must be the issue. That it doesn't come from the same domain page.

Comment: Nothing you can do inside the frame due to *"same origin policy"*

Comment: The only way you can do this is by creating some server-side code to download the page for you, which means it's served by the same domain when you request it.  Do you have any server-side coding knowledge, like PHP or ASP.Net?

Comment: Thanks @Archer. Yes. I think I will have to do that. Actually the issue is cause I am working on my local development env and at the same time displaying data from a remote server (through geoserver). Once the whole app is transfered to the production should be NO problem.

Comment: You can do it if you control code in both pages. Several ways to set it up. postMessage API is one.... setting `document.domain` is another

Comment: Actually I tried to do it by changing my conf file of the nginx server and modify Access-Control-Allow-Origin parameter but didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

$("#id") can not select dom elemets that where added after dom load

$("document").find("#id_iframe").contents()